# ArgumentNullException when saving to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to save changes to a database using EntityFramework, however I get a null excpetion error, but I know the data is not null.

```
  public partial class Model1
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public bool Compulsary { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
}



  private Entity  db = new Entity();
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(string code)
    {

        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["Login"];
        int ID = int.Parse(cookie["ID"]);
        Model1 model1 = new Model1
        {
            ID = ID,
            Code = code,
            Compulsary = false,
            Year = "P2"
        };

        db.Model1.Add(model1);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return View();
    }
```

When it gets to db.SaveChanged then I get an error.

Comment: Just added it to the code.

Comment: The `ArgumentNullException` from Entity Framework in this case usually means that a field that is required in the database, is null in your model. Does the exception have an InnerException?

Comment: @CodeCaster You are absolutely right.

Comment: Can you add structure of Model1?

Comment: Added the Modal. The thing is using intellisense I have checked that the model is filled with the correct data and it is. So I am not sure why this is happening.

Comment: It says "Value cannot be null." But there are no null values in the modal.

Comment: @user1938460, maybe code is null?

Comment: @idlerboris what do you mean code is null?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the Add method and inspect the value of `code`.

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: Oh yeah, I have done that and then I have checked the contents of model1, which are all filled in correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like from here, the Code property could be at fault.

```
int ID = int.Parse(cookie["ID"]);
```

If the above line were at fault, it would fail on that line.  The remaining properties are hard-coded, except for Code.  You could be returning a null value from the post into a (possibly) non-nullable field in the database.

A possible cause is post variable naming.  Check to make sure they are the same name.

Comment: Hard coded the number instead of using the variable ID, still no luck, same error.

Comment: Just noticed that Model1 is a partial class.  Is there another set of Properties that we can't see?

Comment: Sorry for the late response been away. Well Model1 is what was generated by the ADO.net. If that helps? Im not sure what the other properties may be.

Comment: If you could include what is generated by the migration (assuming you're using code-first migrations) that might help.  Look to see if ID is setup to auto increment.  Just pulling at straws since I haven't seen that code yet. :)